# what are the software development methodologies I heard the word agile and what are the other methodologies and which is best and new

Tags: php, json, web, project-management, development-environment

First of all I thank everyone who spend your valuable time here to answer my question .
 what are the software development  methodologies ? I heard the word agile and what are  the other methodologies  and which is best and new?

Comment: any idea about this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each has its pros and cons.

Agile methodologies follow the agile manifesto:

http://www.agilemanifesto.org/

They focus on fast software releases and customer satisfaction, and tend to not give much importance to requirements engineering and documentation.

Some examples:

XP - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming

SCRUM - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)

You can run XP with a team of about 13 members. SCRUM can be run with 5 to 7 members.

On the other hand there are traditional methodologies, one of the most famous being RUP  (Rational Unified Process). This methodology requires a large team. Focus on traceability and documentation. It's generally recommended for critical and large software. Ex: the software that runs an airbus, or controls a self driving car, or a big software like microsoft excel, etc.